# Buscar nome do diretório de um arquivo .bat

Tags: cmd, batch

Eu tenho um arquivo .bat que faz algumas iterações via cmd em vários diretórios.
Meu problema é o seguinte:

- Preciso conseguir pegar o diretório do próprio arquivo .bat para estar sempre voltando ao mesmo para fazer outras iterações.

um exemplo seria:

```
:exemplo
set file=C:\nome-do-diretorio\
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (%file%) do ( cd %%A)
```

Até aqui ok, mas depois preciso que o cmd consiga ser apontado para o diretório do próprio arquivo bat.

Comment: No powershell é `(Get-Location).Path`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar `%~dp0`

```
@echo off
echo "%~dp0"
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar `%cd%`, isso irá retornar o path atual onde o batch está sendo executado.

Pode testar com `echo %cd%`

Comment: Já faço algumas automatizações em batch a algum tempo e não sabia dessa variável. Obrigado.

Comment: É Justamente esta variável que estou utilizando e foi onde descobri o problema. A variável %CD%  pega o diretório atual pra onde esta apontado o cmd. Não queria fazer uma pesquisa em cima do nome do arquivo, pois pode ficar demorado.

Comment: *"mas depois preciso que o cmd consiga ser apontado para o diretório do próprio arquivo bat."* não entendi isso ficou confuso pra mim, você quer o diretório do arquivo bat?

Answer (score 1):

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Você pode usar as variáveis e também as suas expansões de valores/atributos/propriedades.

No código abaixo tens algumas variáveis que são fixas e tens outras que são alteradas conforme as ações do **`bat`**, como exemplo nas trocas de diretórios.

---

```cmd
@echo off & cd /d "%~dpn0"

for %%i in ("%windir%" "%appdata%" "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%")do cls & cd /d "%%~i" & call :^)
goto :eof

:^)
echo/ ----------------------------------------------------------------
echo/ variaveis nao alteram seus valores
echo/ ----------------------------------------------------------------
echo/ %%~d0              = %~d0
echo/ %%~p0              = %~p0 
echo/ %%~dp0             = %~dp0
echo/ %%~f0              = %~f0
echo/ %%~dpnx0           = %~dpnx0     
echo/ ----------------------------------------------------------------
echo/ pasta atual: %__CD__% 
echo/ ----------------------------------------------------------------
echo/ variaveis alteram seus valores para pasta atual
echo/ ----------------------------------------------------------------
echo/ %%CD%%              = %cd%
echo/ %%__CD__%%          = %CD%
echo/ ----------------------------------------------------------------
timeout -t 5 & exit /b
```

---

**Obs.: 1)** Mais informações sobre as expansões de variáveis você tens na ajudo co comando **`for /?`**

**Obs.: 2)** Você pode setar uma variável para usar quando for retornar ao diretório onde o bat inicialmente foi executado dessa forma:

---

```cmd
set "_pasta_bat=%~dp0"

rem :: retornando para a pasta do bat :: 

cd /d "%_pasta_bat%"

rem :: ou apenas :: 

cd /d "=%~dp0"
```